# Can't use enter when editing comments

Tags: generalization

I am trying to edit my comments and separate my responses to make them more clear by pressing enter to give space and make it more understandable, but every time I hit enter it ends the comment and won't allow me to do it. I have to use the space bar to give any separation at all. Example my question here:

Code here followed by hitting enter as such.

I can do it during an initial response such as this, but never during editing a comment to separate code. Sorry for the lame question, but still figuring out the site text rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shift-Enter to add linebreaks in comments. But they don't appear anyway, due to the way comments are formatted on the site.

Comment: It will at least allow me to create space where needed though right?